# Flutter: Error retrieving thread information (os/kern) invalid argument while building iOS apps

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I am encountering an issue while trying to build iOS applications, and I'm seeing the following error message in the logs:

```
[VERBOSE-2:FlutterDarwinContextMetalImpeller.mm(37)] Using the Impeller rendering
backend.
[VERBOSE-2:profiler_metrics_ios.mm(203)] Error retrieving thread information: (os/kern) invalid argument
```

This error is hindering my progress, and I'm not sure how to resolve it. I've tried researching online, but I haven't found any satisfactory solutions. It seems to be related to thread information retrieval, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Thank you.

I have already attempted the following steps:

- Checked for any recent updates to the development environment
- Verified that my Xcode and related tools are up to date
- Ensured that my project settings are correct

Despite these efforts, the issue persists. Can someone please provide guidance on what might be causing this error and how to resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.